# How to monitor operation response time for AWS Elasticache Redis?

Tags: redis, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-elasticache

I'm using CloudWatch to monitor other metrics but I can't find response time metric. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score -1):

Pls configure the following cloudwatch metrics

Read - SelectLatency
Write - DMLLatency